# How to connect to SQL Server Ce database from C#?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, sql-server-ce

How to Connect Sql Server CE Db to C# DotNet 4.0
I've Heard of System.Data.SqlServerCe NameSpace for Connecting local database but i am unable to find it in .Net 4.0

is there any alternate Class?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to have included the **`System.Data.SqlServerCe`** namespace

**Its in** the  **`System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`**

If that namespace doesn't show up then probably you haven't included refrence to that `dll`.

Add a reference to that dll and it should be available.

If you are still having problem then check out its in **GAC**.
(On my system its here:
    `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity\v4.0_4.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91`

Some answers have already mentioned how to use it.

Comment: I have added Refrence to the assembly .. But now I am not having any SqlCe Class .. :S

Comment: Ummm not sure what you mean by that.. but In System.Data.SqlServerCe namespace we have SqlCeConnection, SqlCeDataReader, SqlCeDataAdapter.. and many other classes but no SqlCe class...

Comment: If using the PowerCommands in VS2010, note that the dll appears in the Assemblies list, but in the "Extensions" sub-section rather than "Framework" (cleverly hidden "tabs" on the left side of the dialog).

Answer (score 4):

You need the `System.Data.SqlServerCe` namespace.

```
SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source=\\Mobile\\Northwind.sdf;");
conn.Open();
.
.
.
conn.Close();
```

**From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlserverce.sqlceconnection%28v=VS.100%29.aspx):**

**Namespace:** System.Data.SqlServerCe

**Assembly:** System.Data.SqlServerCe (in system.data.sqlserverce.dll)

Comment: Did you add reference to this assembly?

Answer (score 4):

Open Package Manager Console in Visual Studio to install it from NuGet.
Type: Install-Package SQLCE

Add `using System.Data.SqlServerCe;` to your class

And than use it like:

```
using (var connection = new SqlCeConnection("someConnectionString"))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Comment: Where to Open Package Manager Console .. ^_^

Comment: If you have Visual Stuidio 2010, look for it in View>Other Windows

Comment: I'm getting 'unable to find package sqlce'  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for [System.Data.SqlServerCe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174038%28v=sql.90%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

You can reference **System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll** from the .NET 2.0-3.5 GAC:

`c:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Data.SqlServerCe\4.0.0.0__89845dcd8080cc91\System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll`

It is not in the .NET 4.0 GAC (`C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL`) because it is available for all .NET frameworks since 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks For Your Help guys. I found Reference Dll form **C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server Compact Edition\v3.5\Desktop**